# Suitable kind of database to track a high volume of changes

Tags: python, database, change-tracking

I am trying to implement a python script which writes and reads to a database to track changes within a 3d game (Minecraft) These changes are done by various clients and can be represented by player name, coordinates (x,y,z), and a description. I am storing a high volume of changes and would like to know what would be an easy and preferably fast way to store and retrieve these changes. What kinds of databases that would be suited to this job?

Answer (score 0):

Any kind.  A NoSQL option like MongoDB might be especially interesting.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has a [cube](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/cube.html) module that supports simple storage, indexing and spatial operations on 3D points and cubes.

Comment: Hmm. Might be interesting. Would definately provide a range of options